# scanf doesn't put a terminating null byte

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading a string from `stdin` using the `scanf` function.

```
char inputWord[100];
scanf("%99[^\n]", inputWord);
```

This works fine except the case when the first character in the input sequence is a newline (entered by pressing the `enter key`). When I print the length of inputWord using `strlen`, it prints 6 (always) and when I print the `inputWord` string itself, it prints some garbage. `man` page of `scanf` states that a terminating null byte is added after the first match of a character in the input sequence with the set of excluded characters which here is `[^\n]`. Why is it not adding a null byte in this case? Is it because `scanf` cannot match any character in this case (return value is zero)?

I know I should be using `fgets` but I am just curious to know the behaviour of `scanf` in this case. Seems like `scanf` is one beast of a function.

Comment: change it: `scanf(" %99[^\n]", inputWord);` (added a space before `%` in format string) although you should use `fgets()`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan but the format string `"%99[^\n]"` doesn't ignore leading or trailing white spaces(except a newline in this case) and I don't want to ignore them. I want to read everything except and until a newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return code from `scanf()` in that case will be 0 since it didn't match anything for the conversion spec (and since nothing matched for the conversion spec, nothign is written to the corresponding variable).

Comment: you can add to your answer that he has to initiate his array to 0: `char inputWord[100]={0}`

Comment: so getting strlen(inputWord) as 6 every time I run my code is just pure luck?

Comment: @ajay: Yes this due to Garbage Value initialization of stack variable `inputWord`. May be next time after a couple of hours if you again execute your code, you can get `1000`.